# I don't understand suggested answer for Task 2 in Google Numpy Ultraquick Tutorial

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I've done some Python training but am still a beginner. In the Google Numpy Ultraquick Tutorial, Task 2 asks you to add some noise to a linear dataset you created in Task 1.

Following is my code for Task 1&2:

```py
#Task 1 - create a linear dataset
#Assign a sequence of integers from 6 to 20 (inclusive) to a NumPy array named feature.

feature = np.arange(6, 21)

#Assign 15 values to a NumPy array named label such that: label = (3)(feature) + 4

label = (feature * 3) + 4

#Task 2 - add some noise to dataset
#Modify each value assigned to label by adding a different random floating-point value between -2 and +2.

noise = np.random.randint(-2, 2, size=15)


label = label + noise
```

Following is the suggested answer in the tutorial:

```py
feature = np.arange(6, 21)
print(feature)
label = (feature * 3) + 4
print(label)

noise = (np.random.random([15]) * 4) - 2
print(noise)
label = label + noise 
print(label)
```

I don't understand the second part of the suggested answer. Why is the random array * by 2 and then -2?

Comment: `np.random.random([15])` produces 15 values in [0,1), so that `np.random.random([15]) * 4` produces values in [0, 4), and then `(np.random.random([15]) * 4) - 2` produces values in [-2,2).

Comment: … while the `randint` version produces 15 integer numbers chosen from [-2, -1, 0, 1].